# django celery import function not working

Tags: django, task, celery

I have been trying to create a task for a while, which consists of creating a sample of a specimen every 5 hours. I have managed to configure celery with redis and execute the task that is as an example in the documentation but when I want to do something more complex that includes a query set it does not execute me.the task disappears from the list when restarting the queue.

this is the structure of the project:

```
    proj:
  Muestras:
    -views.py
    -tasks.py
    -models.py
  Servicios:
    -models.py
  proj:
    -celery.py
    -settings.py
```

In settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'generar-muestras': {  # name of the scheduler
   'task': 'Muestras.tasks.crear_muestras_tarea',
   'schedule': 30.0,  # set the period of running
  },
}
```

This is a view that is within Muestras.views

```
from .models import Muestra
from backend.Servicios.models import Servicio

#this works in console
def generar_muestras():
    services = Servicio.models.all()

    for i in services:
        muestra = Muestra(servicio_id=i.id)
        muestra.save
```

In Muestras.tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import task
from .views import generar_muestras


 @task
 def crear_muestras_task():
     print('hola esto tiene una funcion')

     #generar_muestras()
```

this is what i have in celery.py:

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
 import os

 from celery import Celery
 from django.conf import setting

 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

 app = Celery('proj')
 app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
 app.autodiscover_tasks()

 @app.task(bind=True)
 def debug_task(self):
     print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

and when execute

```
celery -A proj worker -l info -B
```

everything works well and executes the task but when I make this line in the Muestras.tasks.py and import from .views the view.

```
         generar_muestras()
```

the task disappears from the list and i get this error:

```
[2018-11-04 22:31:37,734: INFO/MainProcess] celery@linux-z6z3 ready.
[2018-11-04 22:31:37,876: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of 
type 'Muestras.tasks.crear_muestras_tarea'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": 
null}]' (77b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/wecbxxx/PycharmProjects/porj/venv/lib64/python3.6/site- 
packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 558, in 
on_task_received
strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'Muestras.tasks.crear_muestras_tarea'
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your `settings.py` or how you run the celery worker so I am taking a wild guess.

- Your task should be listed under `imports` setting of celery. [See here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-imports).
- Your task should be decorated by `@app.task()`. [See here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#basics)

I suggest you go through [celery's user guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/). I think it can use some structural improvement but should be enough to understand the basics.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @gokhan's answer, there are two things that you should make sure of:

1. Decorate your task with [`@app.task`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#basics)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from proj.celery import app 
from .views import generar_muestras


@app.task
def crear_muestras_task():
    print('hola esto tiene una funcion')
    #generar_muestras()
```

2. Make sure that `Muestras` appears in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.  [This will allow the `autodiscover` to discover your tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django):

> Next, a common practice for reusable apps is to define all tasks in a separate tasks.py module, and Celery does have a way to auto-discover these modules:
>
> ```
> app.autodiscover_tasks()
> ```
>
> With the line above Celery will automatically discover tasks from all of your installed apps, following the tasks.py convention: